# Task queues and result queues with Celery and Rabbitmq

Tags: rabbitmq, celery

I have implemented Celery with RabbitMQ as Broker. I rely on Celery v4.4.7 since I have read that v5.0+ doesn't support RabbitMQ anymore. RabbitMQ is a MUST in my case.

Everything has been containerized then deployed as pods within Kubernetes 1.19. I am able to execute long running tasks and everything apparently looks fine at first glance. However, I have few concerns which require your expertise.

1. I have declared inbound and outbound queues but Celery created his owns and I do not see any message within those queues (inbound or outbound) :

```
inbound_queue =  "_IN"
outbound_queue = "_OUT"

app = Celery()

app.conf.update(
    broker_url = 'pyamqp://%s//' % path,
    broker_heartbeat = None,
    broker_connection_timeout = int(timeout)
    result_backend = 'rpc://',
    result_persistent = True,
    task_queues = (
        Queue(algorithm_queue, Exchange(inbound_queue), routing_key='default', auto_delete=False),
        Queue(result_queue, Exchange(outbound_queue), routing_key='default', auto_delete=False),
    ),
    task_default_queue = inbound_queue, 
    task_default_exchange = inbound_exchange,
    task_default_exchange_type = 'direct',
    task_default_routing_key = 'default',
)

@app.task(bind=True, 
          name='osmq.tasks.add', 
          queue=inbound_queue,
          reply_to = outbound_queue, 
          autoretry_for=(Exception,), 
          retry_kwargs={'max_retries': 5, 'countdown': 2})
def execute(self, data):
  
  <method_implementation>
```

2. I have implemented callbacks to get results back via REST APIs. However, randomly, it can return or not some results when the status is successfull. This is probably related to message persistency. In details, when I implement flower API to get info, status is successfull and the result is partially displayed (shortened json messages) - when I call AsyncResult, for the same status, result is either None or the right one. I do not understand the mechanism between rabbitmq queues and kombu which seems to cache the resulting message. I must guarantee to retrieve results everytime the task has been successfully executed.

```
def callback(uuid):
    task = app.AsyncResult(uuid)
```

Comment: "I have read that v5.0+ doesn't support RabbitMQ anymore" - can you add a reference? I'm working with RabbitMQ + Celery 5.0.5 so I'm not sure where did it come from

Comment: This is pretty cool if I can upgrade to v5.0+. Here, one source: https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/whatsnew-5.0.html#amqp-result-backend

Comment: They are talking about the result backend while you're talking about the broker. I'm using RabbitMQ as the broker + Redis as a result backend.

Comment: my mistake, I would like to use rabbitmq as broker and result backend; couldn't I?

Comment: I guess you can't use it as your result backend anymore (I didn't try). I changed my backend to Redis a long time ago. I am using chord (canvas) and the RabbitMQ behavior, in that case, is bad, sending a message every second and it appeared in my flower

Comment: I do not think Celery will *ever* stop supporting RabbitMQ... What they are saying is something else... And no, you do not want to use a MQ service as result backend - it is simply not made for it. (Redis is completely different story)

Answer (score 0):

Specifically, it was that Celery 5.0+ did not support amqp:// as a result back end anymore. However, as your example, rpc:// is supported.

The relevant snippet is here: https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/getting-started/backends-and-brokers/index.html#rabbitmq

We tend to always ignore_results=True in our implementation, so I can't give any practical tips of how to use rpc://, other than to infer that any response is put on an application-specific queue, instead of being able to put on a specified queue (or even different broker / rabbitmq instance) via amqp://.